# Can't access windows server 2019 installed on VMware from my windows

Tags: windows, server, vmware

I have windows 10 that has VMware. I installed windows server 2019 on it but I don't know how to connect to windows server from my machine, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmad,

If you created the Windows Server 2019 in Windows 10 the default path will be here.

your home directory/Documents/Virtual Machines

If you saved it else where it would have been during setup.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/11/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-ECE9C823-8EE2-44AB-A72B-3C37B76F5193.html